P_values of 1 in LMM
Our team had words learning experiment and we decided to process the data with LMM

That the data structure, it's event-related potential(ERP) on different time intervals and

and then different conditions of experiment, which would be put into the model as fixed(stimulus type, stage of learning, part of experiment) or random effect(subject) on ERP. The problem is taht after using lmer in R we had all p_values of 1 as result
Here is the code
https://github.com/Tima-gaz/LMM/blob/main/LMM_p_values_for_heads_factor_significance.R
Also may be R console output would help

And that's what we basically get (it's composed table with p_values)

I am not very familiar with R and have a feeling like there is just some little detail I foolishly missed. So, thanks in advance for your time and any help on the subject.

This might be more a coding question than a statistics question, but could you explain what each variable of your model is supposed to mean? If the $j$ here is supposed to be your ERPs, then I'm not terribly surprised given the ERP values seem to all be very close to zero in all cases. The coding of those ERPs in your data suggests that perhaps even that is in error, but I know very little about how ERP data is typically processed. More info about your data, particularly what each variable in your model syntax is supposed to be, would be helpful.

It definitely looks like you should rescale your data, i.e., multiply with 1e12.

ERP are neurophysiological responce of brain that was read out by MEG, basically it's the intencity of brain magnetic field(yeah, it's weak), then we had 2 kind of responce depending on stimulus - action and nonaction, so stim_type defines whether subject had to act(press button) or not. Also we had to 2 parts of experiment(first/last), during both 2 stage of learning (early/advanced) because brain responce differently depending how unfamiliar situation is (basic assumption). Yeah, about  in my code, there is 102 sensors where data coming from, and 102 csv files correspondingly. j
is ERP

Roland, Thanks, it helped with problem, but it is a bit confusing, is it like... legal? I mean, where is the source of problem, linear model or R considering all my data to be equal zero and unable to rescale it? And more than that, is there a way to be sure that results on rescaled data are still valid. (I hope I'm not asking too much)

There is nothing wrong with rescaling variables so long as you can still interpret them meaningfully in a model. Say for example I have a continuous variable called minutes of work, where the average is 480 minutes of work achieved in a day. If I divide that by 60, I get hours of work, with the units on a much smaller scale (here 8 hours). So you can rescale whatever you want, so long as you know hot to convey that to others.

Based on the information given I'd say the model runs just fine, and the differences between conditions are so small that the p-values are very high, and rounded to 1. It can be something else too, but I don't think the model or code is the source of the problem here (or rather, it may not be a problem at all, you just have no effects).

Ok, I think I got what you said. Thanks again you guys!

Just to point this out: The issue with very small numbers (and also very large numbers, and in particular, calculations including both very large and very small numbers) is that (limited) accuracy of floating-point numbers (which are used by computers to represent real numbers) starts to matter.
